Deployment Report using MSBuild in SQL Server Database Project
When I publish the SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio, it generates a DeploymentReport.txt file which includes a preview of the changes to apply.
When I publish using MSBuild the file is not created (but the deployment works and all changes are applied).
The deployment report is important for me as it warns me about any unsafe changes that might occur.
Does anyone know if and how I can force MSBuild to generate this file?
The command I'm running:
MSBuild /t:build,deploy 
        /p:TargetDatabaseName="School";TargetConnectionString="..."
        /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="...\\School.publish.xml"

Using Visual Studio:

Using MSBuild:

I tried searching online for a solution, but I couldn't find any relevant solution.
Then I looked into the MS Build documentation but it didn't have any information about what I needed.
I also tried to find any properties specific for the deployment report in the .target files but also didn't help.

I am able to reproduce the same issue with you. From looking at the To publish a database project," Data Tools Operations window will show the progress of your publish operations",it seems Creating publish preview is default progress of publishing in SSDT. A guess: MSBuild maybe ignore some parameters like this.

Try to  check the following command:
MSBuild /t:build,deploy 
        /p:TargetDatabaseName="School";TargetConnectionString="..."
        /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="...\\School.publish.xml"
       /p:DeployReportFileName=DeploymentReport.xml

If it doesn't work, please consider using SqlPackage  instead of Msbuild.
You can use /DeployReportPath: to specifie an optional file path to output the deployment report xml file.
Dor referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16
Hope it can help.
